# In the history of Hinduism and Vaishnavism, has the authenticity of the Puranas ever been questioned?

Tags: puranas, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, srisampradaya

Most Hindus I have spoken to consider the stories and characters of the Puranas to be real. There are modern views that suggest that the stories and characters of the Puranas could be fictional and have more allegorical and symbolic meanings. I wonder whether there is any Vaishnava tradition or person in the history of Hinduism who considers the Puranic stories to be rather fictional and whether this question or doubt about the authenticity of the Puranas was raised at all in ancient India.

Comment: There were schools which did not pay too much attention to the puranas such as the those of Purvamimamsa etc. As for Theological schools such as Vaishnavism or Shaivism, expecting them to hold the puranas as symbolism etc. is preposterous, for the very basis of the majority of their beliefs would shatter if they did so.

Comment: I thought it might not be. For example, in early Christianity, there were churches (docetists) that claimed that Jesus was not a real being and the stories about him were allegorical but revealing of deep truths. I wondered why the Shaivites and Vaishnavas could not have perceived their deities in this way.

Comment: Doubting the prāmāṇya of the Purāṇas, doesn't seem to be the norm among the followers of Vaidika darśanas, sampradāyas and even tāntrikī matas (and sampradāyas). This is more of a standpoint that arose in Hindus, particularly from colonial period, as a result of the thinking of their western masters and the 'education' they received from such masters.
Also, it's better not to compare Hindu tradition with Christianity. There might be 'early' Christianity, but there's no 'early' Hindu tradition, since this is being practiced since time immemorial.

Comment: But the Paurāṇikas  of old tended to accept more pramāṇas than those of darśanas usually, as per some records in śāstras such as Nārāyaṇa Bhaṭṭa's Mānameyodaya. They accepted 8 pramāṇas, the first six are the ones accepted by Advaitins and Bhāṭṭa Mīmāṁsakas, and the remaining two are sambhava & aitihya. It's not like the Vaidika darśanas don't accept these pramāṇas, but these are subsumed in the pramāṇas (which they accept) usually.